# Sonata notification service dependency

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata

So after I did a composer update I had this error:

> The service "sonata.notification.controller.api.message" has a dependency on a non-existent service "sonata.notification.manager.message".

Can someone help me?
What can I do to resolve this?

Comment: I have the same problem. :(

Comment: I'm seeing this problem as well. It looks like the `sonata.notification.manager.message` is set in the dependency injection as a parameter, not a service. If you look at `/vendor/sonata-project/notification-bundle/src/Resources/config/api_controllers`, it's trying to require it as a service, not a parameter. I'm not 100% sure this is the problem, but as far as I could dig.

Comment: https://github.com/sonata-project/SonataNotificationBundle/issues/322

Comment: If I pin composer.json to version 3.3.1 then I don't run into this problem. `"sonata-project/notification-bundle": "3.3.1"`

Comment: Yes, 3.3.1 it is working